# What is the recommended way to change the table name in an HTableDescriptor?

Tags: hbase

Using hbase-client v. 1.1.2.

The `HTableDescriptor` API offers 2 public constructors:

```
  public HTableDescriptor(final TableName name) {...
  ...
  public HTableDescriptor(final HTableDescriptor desc) {...
```

And 2 deprecated methods for changing the table name:

```
  @Deprecated
  public HTableDescriptor setName(byte[] name) {
    setName(TableName.valueOf(name));
    return this;
  }

  @Deprecated
  public HTableDescriptor setName(TableName name) {
    this.name = name;
    setMetaFlags(this.name);
    return this;
  }
```

with no comments about what the user should do instead.

So to clone an `HTableDescriptor`, options are (a) using the first ctor and copying all fields over by hand or (b) use the second ctor and just use the deprecated method to change the table name.

What is the recommended way to do this?  Why doe the API seem to discourage changing the name directly except via ctor?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're looking for [this](https://github.com/apache/hbase/blob/371f2bd9071da0b56565df65c27024c0776942a1/hbase-client/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/HTableDescriptor.java#L373):

```
 /**
  * Construct a table descriptor by cloning the descriptor passed as a parameter
  * but using a different table name.
  * <p>
  * Makes a deep copy of the supplied descriptor.
  * Can make a modifiable descriptor from an UnmodifyableHTableDescriptor.
  * @param name Table name.
  * @param desc The descriptor.
  */
 public HTableDescriptor(final TableName name, final HTableDescriptor desc) {
```

Comment: Sadly, I am using 1.12 which does not include this ctor for some reason.

Comment: @jordanpg well, if you look at the github code you'll see that even in master branch deprecated method is still the only way to change table name.